# Virtual and New in C#

Tags: c#, .net, virtual

I have the following classes in C#:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void DoSomethingVirtual()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base.DoSomethingVirtual");
    }

    public new void DoSomethingNonVirtual()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base.DoSomethingNonVirtual");
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void DoSomethingVirtual()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.DoSomethingVirtual");
    }

    public new void DoSomethingNonVirtual()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived.DoSomethingNonVirtual");
    }
}

class ConsoleInheritanceTrial
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived via Base Reference.");

        BaseClass BaseRef = new DerivedClass();
        BaseRef.DoSomethingVirtual();
        BaseRef.DoSomethingNonVirtual();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Derived via Dereived Reference.");

        DerivedClass DerivedRef = new DerivedClass();
        DerivedRef.DoSomethingVirtual();
        DerivedRef.DoSomethingNonVirtual();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

After running Main function, I got this:

```
Derived Via Base Reference
Derived.DoSomethingVirtual
Base.DoSomethingNonVirtual

Derived Via Derived Reference
Derived.DoSomethingVirtual
Derived.DoSomethingNonVirtual
```

Why did the baseRef.DoSoemthingNonVirtual call the base function? Has it got something to do with the "new" keyword in the Derived Class for that function?
I understand the importance of  "virtual" and "overrides". My confusion was caused by the statement:
BaseClass BaseRef = new DerivedClass();

Comment: The only effect of `new` here is to suppress a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why did the BaseRef.DoSoemthingNonVirtual call the base function?

This is your declaration:

```
BaseClass BaseRef = new DerivedClass();
```

Here you create an object of type `DerivedClass` and you assign a reference of it to a variable that is of type `BaseClass`. This can be done since, the `DerivedClass` has as a base type the `BaseClass`.

Then here

```
BaseRef.DoSomethingNonVirtual
```

you call the method `DoSomethingNonVirtual`.

> What is the type of `BaseRef`?

It is `BaseClass`. So the method of this class is called and not the method of `DerivedClass`.

So the problem here is that you have created an object of type `DerivedClass` and you assigned the reference of this object to a variable of type `BaseClass`. 
So the CLR, when see this call for the first time

```
BaseRef.DoSomethingNonVirtual
```

has to resolve the type of `BaseRef`, then look the object's method table, pick the corresponding IL and at the last produce the corresponding native code. How CLR would resolve this? As an object of type `BaseClass` and not `DerivedClass`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why did the baseRef.DoSomethingNonVirtual call the base function?

Because the compile-time type of `baseRef` is `BaseClass`, the method call was resolved to `BaseClass.DoSomethingNonVirtual()`. The actual type of the object referenced by `baseRef` is `DerivedClass`, but the compiler doesn't know it.

This method is not virtual, so when it's called at run-time, the CLR will simply call the `BaseClass` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

If you define a `virtual` method and you `override` it in a derived class, this method will have the overwritten behaviour in all levels. A base class will use the derived method. That's the reason, why overwritten methods most of the time call their base implementation internally.

With `new` you define a method with the same name - not more...

The base class does not know about this method, so it won't be called.